# Reuse Win+C shortcut after disabling Cortana in Windows 10 1703

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, cortana

We have an application that uses custom key combinations for copy/paste operations. Before we deployed Windows 10 1703 build, users where able to use 'Win-C' combination in the application. 
As Cortana now uses Win+C combination, application is unable to reuse these keys.
What have I tried so far on clean 1703 deployment:

- Disabled Cortana in Group Policies : Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Search.
- Added registry value of type DWORD and set it to 0
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
  VoiceShortcut

The Cortana seems to be disabled now but application still believes Win-C combination is used.
Is there way to find out if Win-C is really in use by Cortana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hotkeys involving the Windows logo key are reserved by the system](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071130-00/?p=24333/)

Applications shouldn't use shortcuts where the Windows Key is involved, it's simply not supported: the behavior will be unpredictable and it may stop working at any time.

> The Windows Logo keys are reserved for system level functions.
>   Software developers should not implement support for the Windows Logo
>   keys[...]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** Just saw this part:

> The Cortana seems to be disabled now but application still believes Win-C combination is used.
>   Is there way to find out if Win-C is really in use by Cortana?

It doesn't solve this question, but it does allow you to reuse the key.

I believe you could send an event from AutoHotKey to your application process, or send another keystroke (such as ctrl+c) to a specific window.

---

I don't know of a builtin way, but you can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) if you'd like:

For example, save the following as `hi.ahk` and start it - press winkey + C and you'll get the `hiiii` message:

```
<#C::
MsgBox, hiiii
```

Comment: `<#C::return` ignores Cortana.